# JavaFx как добавить DirectoryChooser?

Tags: java, javafx

Есть следующий класс:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClientIO extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("client");
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(600);
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(620);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 620, 600));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

И есть класс, который отрисовывает весь GUI:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class GUI {
@FXML
private Button connect;
...
@FXML
private Button disconnect;
private DirectoryChooser directoryChooser;

public void serverConnect(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
Stage stage = (Stage)rootdir.getScene().getWindow();
    File dir = directoryChooser.showDialog(stage);
    if (dir != null) {
        localpath.setText("RootDir!");
    }

}

public void serverDisconnect(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

}
}
```

В методе второго класса хочу вызвать DirectoryChooser для указания директории, но ловлю ошибку. Как я понял я неправильно получаю и передаю ссылку на объект Stage, но пока не понимаю как исправить.
Подскажите каким образом реализовать вызов DirectoryChooser.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Сделал directoryChooser локальной переменной.
В итоге получился код:

```
Stage stage = (Stage)rootdir.getScene().getWindow();
    DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    File dir = directoryChooser.showDialog(stage);
    if (dir != null) {
        localpath.setText(dir.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```